# Deciphering a log based multiple regression result

Tags: multiple-regression, logarithm

I am running a model to understand the impact of different marketing spend on number of orders we generate. I am particularly interested in impact of TV spend. And the orders are particularly from channels like organic, direct and brand sem. I am not adding other channels cause there is a better one to one co-relation between the spend and orders in case of lets say facebook, display etc. So my model looks like something below.

Number of orders(from SEO,Direct & Brand SEM) ~ TV spend + Brand SEM Spend +Non Brand SEM Spend + Display Spend+ Facebook Spend + Quarter (factored) + Time of day (factored)

In the model I realized if I log transform the data then the R square increases(~82%) from (~72%) But in those cases its hard to depict the model. Since its in log transform, its hard to say if I invest 0$ in a channel vs 100$ whats the incremental impact. 
Any suggestion on how to decipher the impact in a log based model.

Comment: Comparing $R^2$ when applying a nonlinear transformation of the response variable is meaningless.

Comment: What would you suggest ? ANOVA of the models? I am also interested in calculating the impact of TV spend. When I spend 0 vs when I spend X amount. Whats the incremental revenue